# What is the big O of this function?

Tags: python, big-o

```
def fd(n):
    x,y,count1,count2 = n,1,0,0
    while (x > 1): (x,count1) = (x/5,1+count1)
    while (y < n): (y,count2) = (count1+y,1+count2)
    return count2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see. The first loop counts how many times `n` can be divided by 5, so `count1` is log(n) (constants don't count for O() calculations). Then the second loop counts how many times `count1` (= log(n)) can be added to 1 to get to `n`, so it basically loops for n / log(n) times.

It looks to me like this is O(log(n) + (n/log(n))).

As J.F. Sebastian points out, n/log(n) dominates log(n), so the final answer should be O(n/log(n)).

Comment: or `O(n/log(n))` (the same thing)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Yeah, that's right, since n/log(n) dominates log(n). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that the answer to this question depends on an agreement about what we are talking about (is important the fact that double numbers are going to be manipulated? do you want a theoretical answer that could sound unsatisfactory or a practical answer?)

Please, let me rephrase this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027842/512225 :

People play a bit fast and loose with big-O notation.

Algorithmic complexity, and hence big-O notation, should be stated in terms of the size in bits of the input, not in terms of the values of the input. Assuming binary input and arbitrarily-large numbers, and N the number of bits of input, N = log(n). 
The complexity is O(exp(N)/N) = O(exp(N)/N) since the second loop requires n/log(n) steps = exp(N)/N steps.

In practice it makes sense to talk about complexity as though N were the input itself, not the size of the input. In that case the complexity of your function is n/log(n).

Anyway we are disregarding the issues given by the fact that n is limited by the definition of double, so that strictly speaking it does not make sense to talk about the asymptotic behavior (with n -> infinity). And we disregard also the fact that if your input is a double them its size is constant and so the complexity of your algorithm is (strictly speaking) O(1) (huge_constant times 1) with huge_constant equal to worst case time (that constant probably depends on the largest number you can express with Python's doubles).

### Summarizing:

the formal answer is O(1) but O(exp(N)) is not that bad as answer, O(n/log(n)) is a good answer too (and probably what you really need).

Comment: O(1)? I think that is not the answer. This function does not take constant time.

Comment: Maybe I didn't write well, maybe I'm wrong. In my opinion, see also the answer I link to, the big-O should depend on input size (not on input value). I'm happy I had some feedback, and I hope we can discuss about it.

Comment: Well you would normally be correct, but in this case the input value _is_ the input size. Notice that the time the function takes changes with the input, so it cannot possibly be O(1).

Comment: I hope I'm not wrong if I say that the size of 1023 is ten and the size of a double is 64. (So the size of the input != value). This is what I meant

Comment: We are using the word size in three different ways. When you read about "the size of the input" they just mean, for example, the number of elements in the collection or whatever. When I say size, I mean the same thing, and when I say value, I mean the number that `n` equals, inside `fd`. When you say it, you mean the number of bits in the number, which has nothing to do with this case.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason why I suggest three answers. All the three are right! Go through the whole answer I linked, I hope it's much well written than mine. Anyway, in this case the size of the input is either 1 or ln(n), while its value is n. Do you agree with the last sentence? I think, we probably are on the same page but we didn't realize it.

Comment: I know Wikipedia is not the bible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Orders_of_growth anyway it can be of help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18245/discussion-between-jimifiki-and-seth-carnegie)