# Computational complexity with "fixed dimension"

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Once I read in a scientific paper:

> The computational complexity of the algorithm is `O(N^d)`, where `N`
>   is the number of data, `d` is the dimension. Hence with fixed
>   dimension, the algorithm complexity is polynomial.

Now, this made me think, that (if I'm not mistaken), big-O notation is defined in the number of binary inputs. Thus if I fix the dimension of data, it is natural to arrive to polynomial solution. Moreover, if I would also fix `N`, the number of input, I would arrive to an `O(1)` solution, see the connected post:
[Algorithm complexity with input is fix-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025543/algorithm-complexity-with-input-is-fix-sized)

My question is, if you think that this is a valid argument for polynomial complexity? Can one really fix one dimension and the input data and claim polynomial complexity?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, the reasoning in the quoted statement is certainly correct.

Comment: Yes, the reasoning in the quotation sounds correct.
My confusion here is that say the input is of size `D = N x d`. Thus, in order to state that the algorithm is polynomial, I would expect the complexity to be a polynomial function of `D`, instead of `N`.

Comment: "the input is of size D = N x d": thats not what is stated there. Instead, the input is of size N and there is a parameter d to the algorithm.

Comment: It's one thing what is stated, and another thing how Ordo, the big-O notation is defined, because big-O notation is defined in terms of bits of input, thus if I have N data points with dimension d, then the input data should be N x d. Still donno if you get my point.

Comment: There is nothing in the definition of big-O notation that states the independent variable is measured in bits, not even that it has to be the input size. The notation is just about growth of functions.

Comment: Correction: How big-O notation makes sense for computational complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a reasonable thing to do.

It really depends on the initial problem, but in most cases I would say fixing number of dimensions is reasonable. I would expect the paper to claim something like "polynomial complexity for practical purposes" or something like that or have some arguments presented why limiting d is reasonable.

You can compare with a solution with complexity O(d^N) where fixing the number of dimensions doesn't mean that the solution is polynomial. So the one presented is clearly better when d is small.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick recall from university time.
Big-O notation is just a **UPPER** bound of how your algorithm perform.
Mathematically, f(x) is O(g(x)) means that there exists a constant k>0 and x0 such that

f(x) <= kg(x) for all x>x0

To answer your question, you cannot fix the N, which is the independent variable.
If you fix N, says <100, we can surely arrive O(1), 
because according to the definition. We can set a large K to ensure f(N) <= kG(N) for all x (<100)

Comment: The main question is not if we can fix N, however I completely agree in what you are stating. The question is if we can fix d or not.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for some algorithms. It is not clear to me, what the "dimension" should be in some cases.

E.g. SubSetSum is is NP-complete, therefor there is no algorithm known with polynomial complexity. But the input is just N numbers. You could also see it as N numbers of bit length d. but the algorithm still has a polynomial complexity.

Same holds for Shortest Vector Problem (SVP) for lattices. The input is a N x N Basis (lets say with integer entries) and you look for the shortest non zero vector. This is also a hard problem and no algorithm with polynomial complexity is known yet.

Comment: Dimension in this case means that the input is of N vectors where each vector has d dimensions

Answer (score 0):

For many problems its not just the size of the input data that makes the problem difficult, but certain properties or parameters of that data. E.g. many graph problems have complexity given in the number of nodes and edges separately.

Sometimes, the difference between this parameters might be dramatic, for example if you have something like O(n^d) the complexity is just polynomial when n grows, but exponential when d grows.

If you now happen to have an application, where you know that the value of a parameter like the dimension is always the same or there is a (small) maximal value, then regarding this parameter as fixed can give you useful inside. So statements like these are very common in scientific papers.

However, you can not just fix any parameter, e.g. your memory is finite, therefore sorting of data is constant time, because the bound on that parameter is so large that viewing it as fixed does not give you any useful insight.

So fixing all parameters is usually not an option because there has to be one aspect in which the size of your data varies. It can be an option if your complexity is very slow growing.

E.g. data structures with O(log n) operations are sometimes considered to have effectively constant complexity if the constant is also quite small. Or data structures as union-find-structures where amortized complexity of the operations is O(α(n)) where α is the inverse of the Ackermann-function, a function growing so slowly that it is impossible to get above 10 or for any size n any hardware imaginable could possible ever handle.

Comment: Indeed, for example in clustering with Support Vector Machines, that trick is known with the enumeration of all possible support vectors is feasible if there are not too many dimensions.